# Front camera fails to open when switching from rear camera

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to switch between the rear and front cameras on pressing a button. But when I try to switch to the front camera, it fails to open and `onCameraFail()` is called.

However, this only happens on the first press.

It works fine on any subsequent presses.

```
private CameraFragment bfc, ffc, current;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    bfc = (CameraFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.camera_preview);

    if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
        ffc = new CustomCameraFragment(true);
        View switchCamera = findViewById(R.id.switch_camera);
        switchCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        switchCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    current = bfc;
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.switch_camera:
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            current =  (current == bfc) ? ffc : bfc;
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.camera_preview, current).commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `FailureReason` passed to `onCameraFail()`? Do you have any problems running the `-v9` version of the demo app?

Comment: @CommonsWare `UNKNOWN`. The camera fails to open.

Comment: @CommonsWare No. That works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a moron, and I am neither logging the exception that triggers the `UNKNOWN` `FailureReason` nor giving you the `Exception` in `onCameraFail()`. I will [fix that](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/210) in the next release. In the meantime, all I can suggest is comparing your implementation to mine from the demo, as the demo is able to switch fragments based on the list navigation. If that's working, then switching fragments is not intrinsically the problem, but it is something else with your configuration.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. I am also facing this same issue. Please let me know how to resolve this. Once it fail mean I can not use the app. If I restart the mobile, then only I can use the app.

Comment: @NewDeveloper: This question is with regards to the CWAC-Camera library, which has been discontinued.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. Thanks for your reply. I need one help. I want to use only back camera. How to restrict to use only back camera.